# The number of my opponents is or the number of my opponents are

Tags: grammar

I was reading the book "1100 Words", and for the section  "Week 19, Day 1" I read the following: (eg https://lelb.net/1100-words-week-19-day-1/)

> **the number of the king’s opponents** who were incarcerated* **were** legion

then I started to read exercises.

> "the number of my followers **is** legion," said the flamboyant politician.

In the first example, we read **"were"** which is plural and the second example shows the same in the singular.

Which is correct and what's the difference if any?

Comment: Please see [A number of questions “has been” or “have been” asked?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked)

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. But does this line  
"The number" is singular. "A number", however, is plural, and takes a plural verb
properly fit the second example from the book?

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times in various forms, and you can find some by searching for "number singular or plural stackexchange".

Comment: I asked a question about the examples from the book. It's easy to Google https://www.dictionary.com/browse/number but I had a question regarding this very example. For me it seems that both sentences are practically the same. But one of them uses plural and the second one uses singular, I'd love to know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject *the number* is singular:

> The number **is** five.
>   The number **is** complex.

It doesn't matter what follows an *of* statement after *number*—the subject remains the singular *number*, regardless of what it might *sound* like.

> The number *of shoppers* **is** large.
>   The number *of mice* **is** alarming.
>   The number *of available vaccines* **is** small.

And:

> The number *of the king's opponents who were incarcerated* **is** legion.

---

However, you could also remove *number of* from the sentence, changing the subject of the sentence to one that *is* plural:

> The king's opponents **were** legion.

Answer (score 0):

> **the number of the king’s opponents** who were incarcerated* **were** legion

I think it's because *were legion* refer to *king’s opponents* and not to *"the number of"*.